# Exception While download byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I tried to convert byte[] to xml file and download the file, I get this exception:

> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

code :

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.xml");
Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.BinaryWrite(fileData);
Response.End();
```

Any one suggest what wrongs with my code ?

Comment: What you see is not the actual exception. That is just what you see because (as it states) the debugger is *"Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack."* which basically means *"I can't tell you the actual value because I can't access it."*

Answer (score 0):

Hi there have you tried the following:

**C#**

```
try
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.xml");
    Response.BufferOutput = true;
    Response.BinaryWrite(fileData);
    Response.Flush();
    //response.End();
    Response.Redirect("",false);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception(e);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the entire method or executing code block with the try catch? Adding a break point at "throw new Exception" and checking  if there isn't something else cooking?

Comment: after adding the line     HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
 not getting exception , nothing happening ( not getting download )

Comment: Try replacing HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); with Response.End again. Otherwise remove Response.Flush() and HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); and try see what the exception is again.

Comment: i have tried this getting different exception : An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.

Comment: now get this exception : Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent."}